# Detached tmux session running command containing variables

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian, tmux

Ok everyone, here is an issue which bugged me for quite some time now:

I am trying to run a bash script, which stores certain values in variables, and then starts another command in a detached session, so that the script can continue running because the command takes ages to finish. That's all fine and nice, but the problem is that the command which should be run in the detached session contains variables. This is not a problem when using screen as the "session manager" (or whatever you want to call a program doing session management):

```
read -p "Session name:" sessionname
read -p "Filename:" filename
screen -S "$sessionname" -d -m nano "$filename"
```

works fine, opening nano in the detached screen as expected. But when i re-attach to the session and close it, my terminal is cleared and sometinmes some of the text from the file is barfed right before my cursor. I realized that this is an issue with how screen works, so i decided to switch to tmux, but now a whole new realm of prblems opens:

```
tmux new-session -d -s "$sessionname" nano "$filename"
```

works fine on cygwin, but on my raspberry 2b running raspbian jessie it throws this error:

```
usage: new-session [-AdDp] [-c start-directory] [-F format] [-n window-name] [-s session-name] [-t tar
get-session] [-x with] [-y height] [command]
```

and trying `tmux ls` afterwards to see if anything started gives me this on the raspberry:

```
failed to connect to server: No such file or directory
```

while on cygwin, if no sessions are running, it gives me this:

```
no server running on /tmp/tmux-197609/default
```

How can it be that tmux on two different plattforms behaves conmpletely different? Have i installed it wrong on the raspberry (`sudo apt-get install tmux`) ?

I am all out of ideas what might be the problem here, so any help is greatly appreciated. (Sorry for confused spelling & grammar, non-native english speaker here)

Comment: Are they different versions of `tmux`? Did you start a `tmux` server on one machine and not the other?

Comment: Yeah, the raspi did for some weird reason apt-get the old version 1.9, which aparrently had some undocumented bugs when trying to run commands in a newly detached window... uninstalling and manually building the newer version 2.0 solved the issue... what a disgrace, i feel truly sorry... sid note: someone should really update the package lists. Thanks man

Comment: apparently they did shortly after i posted this comment, tmux 2.1 is out for raspbian, yay!